# applicationWillTerminate didn't call

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i try to use applicationWillTerminate in my app and i want that in this function i will send data to server,with this:

```
reqURL = [reqURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reqURL]];
NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
NSError *err = nil;
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &resp error: &err];
```

but the problem is that this function didn't call when i close my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the application will be going into the background state, not exiting completely. Try putting your code into:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 4.x, apps are often moved into the background (in order to be quickly resumed) as opposed to being purged from memory.  `applicationWillTerminate:` is only called when the latter occurs.  You probably want [applicationDidEnterBackground](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html): which will be called when your app is quit but continues to stick around in the background.  You will only have about 5 seconds to do any clean-up so you may also want to look into the [beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler%3a) / [endBackgroundTask:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler%3a) methods in case your request is of critical importance and possibly requires more time.

Comment: Not quite; the app can get killed without warning after -applicationDidEnterBackground: returns.

Comment: In fact I tend to avoid `-applicationWillTerminate` altogether on apps that don't explicitly state as non-backgrounding. `-applicationDidEnterBackground` or `-applicationWillResignActive` are probably much better places to put your code.